# Releasing a media file in Windows Media Player Control

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

In my C# code, I tried to delete a video file while I was playing it by Windows Media Player Control.

I stopped playing, made its URL null, and even close the Media Player Control.

```
string delFile = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.sourceURL;

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = null;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();

File.Delete(delFile);
```

However, I have faced 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' because the file was in use.

Is there any way to release the media file connected to my Windows Media Player Control?

Comment: can you delete the video file if it is not played in WMP?

Comment: It's unexpected! I was able to delete it. Is it a permission issue? Can't I delete a file in C# without a special privilege? My file and directory were not read-only, not a system file or directory.

Comment: try `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();` before `File.Delete`

Comment: does it work? please feedback

Comment: Your answer was very helpful although I couldn't solve it yet. File.Delete() does not work on the folder I tested in. I tried to delete it manually but it needs Administrator's privilege although it was not a system folder, but a normal folder created by me. But File.Delete() works on other folders, I am not sure how the process was when I created the problematic folder. It is very certain that the exception is not because of Windows Media Control.

Comment: The folder's owner was not me, so I changed it to me. Now it does not need a special privilege. I don't know how it was changed (during USB file backup???). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was able to release the media file using the suggestion provided by @kennyzk above:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist.clear();
```

Comment: Although, that is counter-intuitive, this solution just works. Thanks.